# ASP.NET Core - How to resolve Message=Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

In ASP.NET Core-6 project, I am sending SMS notification. I have these models:

```
public class NotifyRequestResponse
{
    public string ResponseCode { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<string> Result { get; set; }
}

public class NotificationPayload
{
    public string PhoneNo { get; set; }
    public decimal amount { get; set; }
    public string Receiver { get; set; }
    public string Pin { get; set; }
    public string RegNo { get; set; }
}
```

Then followed by this method:

```
private async Task<bool> SendSmsAsync(string phoneNumber, string subject, string smsTemplate)
{
    var requestModel = new SendSmsDto
    {
        Mobile = phoneNumber,
        SmsTemplate = smsTemplate,
        Subject = subject
    };
    var notificationResponse = await _dataAccess.SmsNotificationAsync(requestModel);
    var notificationResult = await notificationResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NotifyRequestResponse>(notificationResult);
    if (result.ResponseCode == "00")
        return await Task.FromResult(true);
    return await Task.FromResult(false);
}
```

Then finally I called the method here:

```
var smsSenderValidityResult = await SendSmsAsync(payload.PhoneNo, "MyApp", $"You sent" + Environment.NewLine + $"Amount: " + payload.amount + $"to" + Environment.NewLine + $"Receiver: " + payload.Receiver + Environment.NewLine + $"PIN: " + payload.Pin + Environment.NewLine + $"RegNo: " + payload.RegNo);
```

I got this error:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
  Source=Newtonsoft.Json
```

It points to these lines of code:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NotifyRequestResponse>(notificationResult);
```

and

```
var smsSenderValidityResult = await SendSmsAsync(payload.PhoneNo, "MyApp", $"You sent" + Environment.NewLine + $"Amount: " + payload.amount + $"to" + Environment.NewLine + $"Receiver: " + payload.Receiver + Environment.NewLine + $"PIN: " + payload.Pin + Environment.NewLine + $"RegNo: " + payload.RegNo);
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the value `notificationResult` in the following line is not valid Json:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NotifyRequestResponse>(notificationResult);
```

The cause is most likely that the call:

```
var notificationResponse = await _dataAccess.SmsNotificationAsync(requestModel);
```

is getting a failure from the endpoint accessed.

Put a breakpoint on the line where you're trying to deserialize the result and inspect the value of `notificationResult` from the previous line:

```
var notificationResult = await notificationResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

That should tell you what error is being thrown by the `SmsNotificationAsync` call.